# Links \href - remove the tooltip

Tags: hyperref

I have a big document in LaTeX and I use a lot of `\href{<url>}{<text to display>}`.
But some URLs are very long (mostly about 200-220 characters) and then the tooltip is huge and overpass the document limit (ugly). Additionally, this could hide some important text just under the mouse pointer.

My first idea was to convert those URL into shorter ones (like `go.gl/xxxxxx` or `bit.ly/xxxxxxxx`), but those links are not available in my network company. I mean if a basic user like you click on it, no problem because you have a free internet access but you won't access to those URLs because you are not physically in my network company. Conversely, in my work place, there is no internet (only a local one), so those links couldn't work.

**So my question is :**

- Is there any option to "hide" this tootip when using the command `\href`?
- Is there instead a way to customise the command `\href` to hide the tooptip?
- If no solution exist for the `\href` command, does any other command can do what I am looking for?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is dependent on the PDF viewer you use. For example the one I use (MuPDF) doesn't show any tool-tips at all when I mouse over a link set by `\href`. I'm therefore voting to close this as Off-topic.

Comment: @Skillmon That a problem cannot be solved at TeX level does not automatically mean that the problem is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `hyperref` uses `/URI` as action type for URLs in `\href`. It does not set any tool tip. This is done by the PDF viewer. Some viewers (AR, evince) show a tool tip with the URI, others (xpdf) show the URI in the status line of the program. This behavior of the PDF viewer cannot be configured by the PDF file and therefore not by `hyperref`.

Comment: Thanx for this answer. However, if hyperref use the /URI action, can the tooltip be edited with Javascript ? Like forcing the display property to "none" or "invisible" ?

Comment: @huguesdpdn Also, at JavaScript level I have not seen a "tool tip" property for URI annotations. But see yourself: [PDF Reference](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html), [Acrobat JavaScript Object Specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/5186AcroJS.pdf).

Comment: Indeed. Only one related subject to the tooltip [reference in page 259 second second paragraph](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/5186AcroJS.pdf#page=259) is mentionned but only for the description. This description, if you set it as empty (or `""`), you do not follow the URL. So no way to do what I want to do. Thank for all